# Api call not working in online web page

Tags: php, html, api

when i trying to call the below api call using the below code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo $json; exit;
```

It's giving me response in one hosting.

When i trying the same api in reseller club hosting package site. It's not loading the page as well. It is giving connection time out error.

can any one suggest the solution for this.

Comment: if it works from one server but not another, then start into checking of that non-working server can even reach the api's server. e.g. it could be firewalled, blacklisted, blocked, etc.. And as a general tip, if you're having trouble with code, you should **NEVER** suppress errors with `@`. It's the equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "la la la la don't want to hear you tell me what the problem is I'm ignoring you lalalalala"

Comment: Most likely such requests are not permitted on the host where the call fails. Check your php settings, look for `safe mode` and `allow_url_fopen`...

Comment: sorry that's my bad ..after trying with @..just copied same lines on above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i talk to the server guy's they resolved the issue. they said that  outbound connections to port 80 from my website was blocked in there server which was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your host may block outgoing HTTP connections - there's nothing you can do about that (other than upgrading to a service plan which allows that).

Also hiding error messages with @ is evil (imho)